# how to match values in two different pytorch tensors using a condition

Tags: pytorch

i have 4 tensors

```
ib0 = torch.tensor([14,17])
bb0 = torch.tensor([0,1])
ib1 = torch.tensor([17,4,2])
bb1 = torch.tensor([0,0,1])
```

i need to get another tensor which matches the values in ib0 and ib1 based on the values of bb0 and bb1. the result i am looking for is

```
torch.tensor([[14,17],[14,4],[17,2]])
```

because the index of 0 (from bb0) in ib0 has value 14 and the indices of 0 (from bb1) has values 17,4 in ib1 and similar for the index of 1 in bb0. 
This is needed in a beam search algorithm to merge together indices from the same beam. The bb0 and bb1 tensors are beam indices while ib0, ib1 are the indices in the 2 beams 0 and 1. So the above procedure is just a way to make sure that indices from different beams do not merge.

Comment: Since `bb0` and `bb1` have different length, how can they be merged in a single output? Can you provide the logic in form of some code, e.g. using numpy or `for` loops or something similar.

Comment: @a_
`[(ib0[x],ib1[y]) for x in range(len(bb0)) for y in range(len(bb1)) if bb0[x]==bb1[y]]`

Comment: @a_guest
 is there a more efficient way of doing the above in numpy/pytorch using indexing

Comment: You say you need this for a "beam merge algorithm", I'm not sure what that is but it sounds like there are always going to be exactly two beams? And hence the `bb0` and `bb1` tensors only consist of ones and zeros? Or do you want to stack more than two beams eventually?

Comment: Not really @a_guest. Sorry I should have mentioned that there can be an arbitrary number of beams.   Hence the need to not use loops

Comment: Could you update your question with an example for three beams please? It'll be easier to figure out the generalization then.